# Angular js - Add data to existing model on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want add data to the existing model post submitting the data, below is the code

HTML Code

```
<input type="text" ng-model="configData.A1" />
<input type="text" ng-model="configData.A2" />
<input type="text" ng-model="configData.A3" />
<input type="text" ng-model="configData.A4" />
<button class="btn" ng-click="saveData(configData)">Save Data</button>
```

Angular js code

```
$scope.saveData = function (configData) {
   //Want to add below commented data into existing configData
   //configData.uniqueId = $scope.config.uid;
   //configData.uniqueName = $scope.config.uName;
   $http.post(saveConfigData_api, configData).then(function (data) {
        $('#progressbar').hide();
   });
 };
```

Comment: Use `$scope` to make changes to your model object

Comment: Why not use an array in configData instead of A1, A2, A3... And then you can use a repeater to generate as many inputs as the number of elements there. And as others pointer out, on your click, you don't have to pass your configData because the function handler will have access to $scope and can work with the data directly.

Comment: SOLVED: By adding two hidden fields for uniqueId and uniqueName

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to pass the `configData` in `saveData` function as it is a model data in AngularJS so you can access it through `$scope`. Passing that as a function parameter will not reflect the changes in `configData` model. So, change your code to

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="configData.A1" />
<input type="text" ng-model="configData.A2" />
<input type="text" ng-model="configData.A3" />
<input type="text" ng-model="configData.A4" />
<button class="btn" ng-click="saveData()">Save Data</button>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.saveData = function () {
   $scope.configData.uniqueId = $scope.config.uid;
   $scope.configData.uniqueName = $scope.config.uName;
   $http.post(saveConfigData_api, configData).then(function (data) {
        $('#progressbar').hide();
   });
 };
```

Using `$scope.configData` will make changes to the `configData` model.

Comment: Did not work with the following error "Cannot set property 'UniqueId' of undefined"

Comment: set `$scope.configData = {}` at the top of your controller which is used by that HTML @user8624282

Comment: doing that i'll lose data from input elements which i pass to my controller

Comment: since you are using `ng-model="configData.A1"` you need to initialise that $scope.configData = {
      A1: '',
      A2: '',
      A3: '',
      A3: ''
    } 
in controller

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.saveData = function (configData) {
   //Want to add below commented data into existing configData
   configData.uniqueId = $scope.config.uid;
   configData.uniqueName = $scope.config.uName;
   $http.post(saveConfigData_api, configData).then(function (data) {
        $('#progressbar').hide();
   });
 };
```

This should do the trick, *or i understood the question wrong.*

Comment: I want to add new data into  existing configData before post

Comment: if thats the case, just do what you have in the comments (see updated answer)